# Mono compile error due to namespace name does not exists

Tags: c#, mono

I'm using mono on macOS and trying to compile this C# code: https://gist.github.com/bneg/bf8c05664324e3efeb1fb05902152a20

with following command:

```
mcs Program.cs
```

It produces following error:

```
Program.cs(4,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Management' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(5,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Management' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I also tried it with following command:

```
mcs -pkg:dotnet Program.cs
```

I got this error:

```
Program.cs(17,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Automation' does not exist in the namespace `System.Management'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(18,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Automation' does not exist in the namespace `System.Management'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

What changes should be made in order to compile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can run powershell like that via mono on mac os.

As a minimum you would need to reference something like this:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation

But this is not guaranteed to be working if you do not have powershell installed. And since powershell on linux (sic!) can [only run on .net core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2613), chances are, you cannot get what you are trying to accomplish.